# Git server on a local company server + files

Tags: git

Im trying to set a remote Repo on my company file server using GIT.

I want to push local files and changes from my local machine Repo to the "remote" Repo on my company file server.

Im the only user working on the project.

1. I can not use a bare Repo, as i want the files to be pushed to the "remote".
2. Clone local to remote generate an error when trying to PUSH

The error:
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false --no-optional-locks push -v --tags origin master:master
Pushing to M:/ARC/MikeS
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: 
remote: You can set the 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable
remote: to 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: other way.
remote: 
remote: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.

To M:/ARC/MikeS
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to 'M:/ARC/MikeS'

Completed with errors, see above.

I tried using "git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore" on the Remote Repo.
the error is cleared, but the file on the remote Repo. are not getting updated.

Is there any solution? 
I know it sounds very straightforward, but i just can not get it to work.

Thank you,
Mike

Comment: sorry, I do not understand the question

Comment: "an error when trying to PUSH" - what error? And what did you do exactly?

Comment: Did my answer addressed your question?

Answer (score 0):

Using a bare repo (through SSH) is a good solution, provided you have the right pre/post-receive hook, which will checkout your files in a non-bare repository.

- pre-receive hook to check that your remote repository has not had any change/new commits done (in which case you would pull from it first, merge locally, then push to the bare repository)
- post-receive hook: to checkout the content you are pushing to the non-bare repository, making the files visible.

Meaning: on your remote server, you create two repositories:

- one non-bare (for working directly on the server)
- one bare (to push from your local machine)

That is:

```
ssh remoteUser@remoteServer
git init newRepo
cd newRepo
git init --bare bare
```

Then on your local machine, you clone the empty new (non-bare repository), *but* you modify the push URL to reference the bare repository (`newRepo/bare`)

```
git clone remoteUser@remoteServer:~/newRepo
cd newRepo
git config --add remote.origin.pushurl remoteUser@remoteServer:~/newRepo/bare
```

On the remote server, in ~/newRepo/bare/hooks, add a pre-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$(readlink "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" )" && pwd )"

git fetch

# Read stdin for ref information
while read -r oldref newref refname; do

  case "${refname}" in
  */master) branch="master"
  ;;
  refs/tags/*)
    ok "Pushing tag: proceed"
    exit 0
  ;;
  *) echo "invalid branch '${refname}'"
  exit 1
  ;;
  esac

  if [[ "${newref}" == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ]]; then
    ok "Deletion of oldref '${oldref}': pre-receive proceed"
    exit 0
  fi

  localsha1=${newref}

  if [[ "master" == "${branch}" ]]; then
    originsha1=$(git rev-parse origin/master)

    force="false"
    # shellcheck disable=SC2086
    if [[ "$(git rev-list ${oldref} ^${newref})" != "" ]]; then force="true"; fi

    cmd="git merge-base --is-ancestor ${originsha1} ${localsha1}"
    if ! eval "${cmd}"; then
      if [[ "${force}" == true ]]; then
        info "force push master"
      else
        fatal "Git push of '${refname}' refused because repo locally ($(hostname)) modified\nDo a git pull first" 1
        exit 1
      fi
    fi
    if git rev-parse --quiet --verify from_prod >/dev/null && ! git merge-base --is-ancestor from_prod "${localsha1}"; then
      error "Git push of '${refname}' refused because from_prod is not an ancestor"
      error "Meaning: prod has evolved, fetch and rebase on top of from_prod first, then push again"
      exit 1
    fi
    ok "Push to master will proceed"
  fi
done
```

And a post-receive hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$(readlink "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" )" && pwd )"

while read -r oldrev newrev refname
do
  case "${refname}" in
  */master) branch="master"
  ;;
  refs/tags/*)
    ok "Pushing tag: proceed post-receive"
    exit 0
  ;;
  *) fatal "invalid branch '${refname}' in post-receive (oldrev:'${oldrev}')" 1
  ;;
  esac

  if [[ "${newrev}" == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ]]; then
    ok "Deletion of oldrev '${oldrev}': post-receive proceed"
    unset GIT_DIR
    cd ..
    git --work-tree=. --git-dir=.git fetch --prune
    if [ "${branch}" != "" ]; then git --work-tree=. --git-dir=.git branch -d "${branch}"; fi
    cd ./bare || fatal "Unable to go into bare of '$(pwd)'" 8
    git --git-dir=. fetch --prune
    exit 0
  fi

  info "post-receive for branch '${branch}'"
  if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
    info "pull from non-bare repo"
    unset GIT_DIR
    cd ..
    git --work-tree=. --git-dir=.git fetch
    git --work-tree=. --git-dir=.git fetch --tags
    if ! git --work-tree=. --git-dir=.git merge-base --is-ancestor master origin/master; then
      info "Reset non-bare master to bare master (forced update)"
      git  --work-tree=. --git-dir=.git reset --hard origin/master
    else
      info "Update non-bare master with merge from origin/master"
      git --work-tree=. --git-dir=.git pull --no-rebase origin master
    fi
  fi
done
```

That way, you can work both directly on the server, in your regular ~/newRepo non-bare repo, making commits.
But you can also work on your machine, and push without fear of overriding a remote commit made concurrently on the server: the pre-receive hook would block the push.

Notes:

- replace the "`ok`", "`info`" and "`fatal`" with simple "`echo`" in the scripts).
- Add `bare/` in your `.gitignore`, for your regular repository to ignore its nested bare repo.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.

i saw that use PULL on the server Repo. also do the trick.
is it safe to use this method?

Comment: @user159348 Yes, my constraint was: the remote server could not pull from my local machine, I could only push from the local machine to the remote server. Hence the hooks.